# Any formula to replace multiple values on google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet problem that looks like this:

[Google Sheet Image Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLJpt.png)

In Column "A" I have a group of IDs organized in a specific way.

In Column "B" I have a list with all the IDs present in column "A" and their specific audience name. The names and IDs are separated by ";" and the ID is the number between "( )".

I need a formula or solution that replaces the ID on column "A" with the audience name referenced on column "B".

Here's a link to the example sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BS6_frcliNV882kWcDb2ZjpjERdPtI_ZiivWzHvRVuk/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

In your situation, for example, how about using Google Apps Script? I thought that when Goolgle Apps Script is used, your goal might be able to be achieved using a simple script. The sample script is as follows.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Google Spreadsheet. And, please put a custom function of `=SAMPLE(A2:B)`. By this, the script is run.

```js
function SAMPLE(values) {
  const obj = values.flatMap(([, b]) => [...b.matchAll(/(.+?) \((.+?)\);?/g)].map(e => [e[2].trim(), e[1].trim()]));
  return values.map(([a]) => obj.reduce((s, e) => s.replace(...e), a));
}
```

#### Testing:

When this script is run to your provided Spreadsheet, the following result is obtained.

[image]

#### Note:

- This sample script can be used for your provided Spreadsheet. When you change the structure of each value, this script might not be able to be used. Please be careful about this.

#### References:

- [Custom Functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)